# Este codigo no funciona en php 7.2, alguien tiene idea?

Tags: php, array, variables

Me funcionaba en 5.6 pero se paso a 7.2 el servidor y dejo de funcionar todas las variables quedan en blanco.

```
$decoded = json_decode($params['datos'],true);

foreach ($decoded as $value) {
    $$value["name"] = addslashes($value["value"]);
}
```

$decoded recibe esto:

```php
array(23) {
  [0]=>array(2) {
      ["name"]=>string(3) "tki"["value"]=> string(65) 4544545454"
  }
}
```

Comment: necesitamos por ejemplo una muestra de los valores que recibe `$decoded` para poder comprender y si es posible si es que aparece algún error

Comment: hay que ponerle llaves `${$value["name"]}` para que no sea ambiguo https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect , el `$$value["name"]` php 7.x lo interpreta como `($$value)["name"]`

Comment: lo probe asi tambien y tampoco me funciona, no se que puede ser

Comment: puede que haya un error en el parseo, fijate que dice [`json_last_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php), [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#refsect1-function.json-decode-changelog) en php 7.x es un poco mas estricto